# Cannot run GameMaker Studio 2 .sh file on Banana Pi M1 board

Tags: display, games, armbian

I'm having problems running a game I made in GameMaker Studio 2 on a Banana Pi M1 board using Armbian.

**I've done:**

1. Installed Armbian Bionic 18.04.02 (Ubuntu-based) on a Banana Pi M1 board.
2. Installed a GUI (which I think is XFCE).
3. Programmed an arcade style shooter game on my Windows PC in GameMaker Studio 2.
4. Built the game from GameMaker on my Windows PC to the Banana Pi board, which connects and executes Armbian just fine.

**Issue:**

- The game does not start in step 4. GameMaker states that it has been built and should be running just fine but I cannot run the game on the Banana Pi board, neither from Terminal nor from GUI.

**I've tried:**

- Running from GUI. The file simply does not run,
- Executing `sh execute.sh` from Terminal (not a window in the GUI, but by exiting the GUI with Ctrl+AltF1) but that gives me the error

  > xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s xterm: DISPLAY is not set
- Executing `sh runner` which gives me the error:

  > runner: 1: runner: Syntax    error: "(" unexpected.**
- Typing `export DISPLAY=:0` before #1 and #2 above removes the error messages, but still does not run the game/file.
- Using `gedit` from a console, I also get the `cannot open display` error.
- Opening up a terminal window in my GUI, fails without error.

**Content of my execute.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -x "$(command -v xtern)" ]; then
xterm -e bash -c "$1; sleep 10"
elif [ -x "$(command -v gnome-terminal)" ]; then
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "$1; sleep 10"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **:-)** Can you try executing the game from a terminal within the GUI? (Press [Ctrl][Alt][T] to open a GUI terminal.) also post the contents of `execute.sh`.  Please [edit] your question and don't put this relevant info here in the comments so that your question stands by itself and please also use the `{}` button to format text as code.

Comment: Thanks you, @Fabby. I have edited the post with the content of my execute.sh and two pieces of further information. I'm starting to think that maybe Armbien isn't compatible with GameMaker files. Or at least the Armbien available for the Banana Pi M1 board.

Comment: Opening the terminal from the GUI works or running the game from a terminal in the GUI works?

Comment: Neither works. Double-clicking the file from the GUI gives me no response (nor does right-click and choosing execute). The game gives out the error messages stated above, when I open it from terminal (I enter terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1).

Comment: Please follow the original instructions: start the GUI, *then open a GUI terminal, **not a console*** by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and then execute the program there, then [edit] your question and provide any error messages there (*As you didn't mention you wrote a text-only game*, I'm assuming it's graphics-based. And to graphics-based games [Ctrl][Alt][F1] is a deadly enemy *as that's a console, not a terminal!*  **0:-) ;P** )